# php - how to display values from a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

how do i display individual values from the following code?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [@attributes] => Array 
            ( 
                        [stat] => ok 
                        ) 
                        [profile] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                        ( 
                        [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                        ( 
                        [country] => United Kingdom 
                        ) 
                        [displayName] => gareth 
                        [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                        ( 
                        [givenName] => Gareth 
                        [familyName] => Davies 
                        [formatted] => Gareth Davies 
                        ) 
                        [preferredUsername] => gareth 
                        [providerName] => Google 
                        [verifiedEmail] => gareth@spyre-media.com 
                        )
                        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SimpleXML section of the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) does a good job showing how to access data in the object.

Taken (some editing) from the manual, this shows the basics:

Accessing a node:

```
$xml->movie //first 'movie' node
```

Accessing a specific node

```
$xml->movie[0] //first 'movie' node
```

Accessing a secondlevel node:

```
$xml->movie[0]->rating
```

Accessing a node's attribute:

```
$xml->movie[0]->rating['type']
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes in SimpleXML elements can be displayed by simply using the array accessor.

```
$simpleXml = ...
$givenName = $simpleXml['givenName'];
```

Comment: $simpleXml = ... ?

would this be written

$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($auth_info); 
$givenName = $simpleXml['givenName'];
echo $givenName;

Answer (score 0):

Array accessors only work for the @attributes sub-keys.

You can either use the arrow notation to access the properties:

```
$simpleXml->name->formatted;
```

Or cast the SimpleXmlElements individually to use array accessors:

```
$sxa = (array)$simpleXml->profile;
echo $sxa['displayName'];
```

If you go the casting route, you have cast at every level containing additional elements.